# DropdownButton value resets after going back

Tags: flutter, dart

I am implementing a `dropdownButton` with two options [English and Urdu], dropdown is implemented successfully and holds the value but the selected value on the main dropdownButton resets after I move back a page and enter again while the functionality works (meaning if I had selected Urdu the urdu language is shown but the dropdownMenu shows English)

What am I doing wrong?

**Main Class where I am calling TranslationMode class**

```
class OptionScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const OptionScreen();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Padding(
            padding: kPagePadding,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                ShowTranslationOption(),
                Divider(),
                TranslationMode(),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**TranslationMode Class**

```
class TranslationMode extends StatefulWidget {
  const TranslationMode({super.key});

  @override
  State<TranslationMode> createState() => _TranslationModeState();
}

class _TranslationModeState extends State<TranslationMode> {
  String selectedValue = 'English';
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0.h),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: [
          Text('Translation mode',),
          DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
            child: BlocBuilder<QuranThemeBloc, QuranThemeState>(
              builder: (context, state) {
                return DropdownButton(
                    value: selectedValue,
                    items: [
                      DropdownMenuItem(child: Text('English'), value: "English"),
                      DropdownMenuItem(child: Text('Urdu'), value: "Urdu"),
                    ],
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      BlocProvider.of<QuranThemeBloc>(context).add(
                        SwitchTranslationMode(value!),
                      );
                      setState(() {
                        selectedValue = value;
                      });
                    });
              },
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: This English description shown for selected language gets resets to English even after selecting other language]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your issue:

```
class _TranslationModeState extends State<TranslationMode> {
--> String selectedValue = 'English';
```

Every time your component is called, the selected value is always English, even if your provider is working fine.

What you need is to store the selected value somewhere outside your widget, and read the value whenever the widget is called.

Comment: removing `String selectedValue = 'English';` worked, I was already storing the value.